# Preference Activity Deprecated Methods

Tags: android, android-preferences, deprecated

When I changed the app min-API level from 8 to 11, all of my `getPreferenceScreen` methods seem deprecated and `setSummary` methods stopped working.

When I try to set the value in `onSharedPreferenceChanged` I don't get the same value I gave:

```
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_USERNAME).setSummary(username);
```

I figured out that I should use `PreferenceFragments` instead of `PreferenceActivity` since changes were made after API level 11 and above.

Why didn't they just completely remove this getPreferenceScreen method? I should still be able to use depreciated methods, right?

Otherwise how can I best implement new `PreferenceFragment` to get rid of these deprecated methods with minimal effort?

Answer (score 0):

> PreferenceActivity is the base class for an activity to show a
>   hierarchy of preferences to the user. Prior to HONEYCOMB this class
>   only allowed the display of a single set of preference; this
>   functionality should now be found in the new PreferenceFragment class.
>   If you are using PreferenceActivity in its old mode, the documentation
>   there applies to the deprecated APIs here.

check below link for more detail

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Comment: Thank you sir. I read this document. And it is indicated in the document that 
This getPreferenceScreen method was deprecated in API level 11. This function is not relevant for a modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity. But it doesnt mean "you can't use it" since i am not using fragment-based Activity.